# question on Hibernate Criteria API

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I have a two table A and B:

```
A columns (ID,NameA,BiD)
B columns (ID,NameB)
```

ID is referenced to Bid as foreign RelationMapping. 
Here is the problem .My Hibenate B Entity has not got List but My hibernate A entity has got B entity instance.

```
select a.* from A a, B b 
where a.BiD=b.ID
```

How can ı do this query in Hibernate Criteria Api?
I hope I can explain my problem?

Comment: have you mapped A and B to classes?

Comment: Yes but only in A class mapped for B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to join the classes in the query. This information is in the mapping file. If you load A's, the B's are loaded (probably lazily) too.

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(A.class).list();
```

If this answer doesn't help, you forgot to provide some information about the query you need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you want is to find all A instances having a specific B ID

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(A.class, "a");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("a.b.id", theIdOfB);
return c.list();
```

If you had to search on B's name rather than B's ID, you would need a join:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(A.class, "a");
c.createAlias("a.b", "b");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("b.name", theNameOfB);
return c.list();
```

As always, all this is explained with examples in [the reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria).

Comment: Excuse me,Again I am trying explain my question.

A columns (ID,NameA,BiD)
B columns (ID,NameB)    Table Structer

in A class for B Class

    @JoinColumn(name = "BID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@ManyToOne
private B bid;



in B class no mapping for A class

and Now 
I want to get B.NameB that used in A table(BiD)
How can ı do with Projection or Criteria?

Comment: Read the documentation: what you want to do is very easy and explained in this documentation. If you're really stuck, then ask another question. Note that the bid field of the class A should be named "b". It's a B instance, and not an ID.